# Nodejs and Jade rendered my submit button as a text field

Tags: node.js, forms, pug

In a nodejs application, with Jade templating, I can't manage to render a submit button.

This is my app.js code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/todo', function(req,res){
  res.set({
    "Content-Type" : "text/html",
    "charset" : "utf-8"
  });
  res.render('todo_list.jade', {list : [
    "Lire un livre", "Jouer de la musique", "Apprendre la programmation", "Jouer au dé pipé !"
  ]});
});

// app.post('/todo/ajouter', function(req, res){
//
// });
// 
// app.post('/todo/supprimer/:id', function(req, res){
//
// });

app.listen(8080);
```

This is my view/todo_list.jade :

```
doctype html

head
  title Ma todo list

body
  h1 Ma todo list
  ul
    - for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        li #{list[i]}
  form
    label(for=new_task) Que dois-je faire ?
    input(type=text, id=new_task, name=new_task, size=15)
    input(type=submit, value=Ajouter)
```

So why I am getting two text fields instead of a text field and a button ?

In my application root folder, I've installed (with a package.json file) express ~4.3.2, cookie-session ~1.0.2, body ~4.4.2, and jade ~1.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that you are not properly assigning attributes to your tags.  In Jade, attribute values are evaluated as JavaScript expressions. This means that leaving your attribute values unquoted will use the variable's value rather that the literal value.

Here is the fixed Jade template that will give you the desired output:

```
doctype html

head
  title Ma todo list

body
  h1 Ma todo list
  ul
    - for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        li #{list[i]}
  form
    label(for='new_task') Que dois-je faire ?
    input(type='text', id='new_task', name='new_task', size=15)
    input(type='submit', value='Ajouter')
```